# Implications of some sort of $l^2$/uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Sorry about the title, but I couldn't really figure out how to describe my problem in one sentence... I'm having some problems with real limits:

For $f,g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ let $\mathcal{F}(f,g) := \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} (f(k) - f(k+1))(g(k)-g(k+1))$ and let $D := \left\lbrace f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}~ | ~ \mathcal{F}(f,f) < \infty \right\rbrace$. For $v \in \mathbb{N}$ set $o_v(f,g) := f(v)g(v)$. Then $\mathcal{F} + o_v$ provides a complete inner product on $D$. So far so good.

Now fix $v \in \mathbb N$ and suppose we have some fixed function $f$ and a sequence of functions $f_n$ converging in $D$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}(f_n - f) + o_v(f_n -f)\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Obviously, it follows that $f_n \to f$ point-wise and even
$$\sup\limits_{x \in \mathbb{N}} |f_n(x)-f_n(x+1) - (f(x)-f(x+1))| \to 0$$
i.e. we have some sort of uniform convergence.

My question is: Can I produce some statement along the lines of $f_n(n) \to \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$?

Thoughts, help and hints are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: $v \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed, right? If so: Why is it obvious that $f_n \to f$ pointwise? (I guess, I'm missing something obvious...)

Comment: @saz: Yes $v \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed. However, it can be chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: @saz: Well, it follows that $\mathcal{F}(f_n - f) \to 0$ and $o_v(f_n -f) \to 0$. Hence, $f_n(v) \to f(v)$ and for any $x \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(f_n(x)-f(x) - (f_n(x+1)-f(x+1)))^2 \leq \mathcal{F}(f_n -f) \to 0$. This implies that $f_n(x)-f_n(x+1) \to f(x) - f(x+1)$ for all $x$. Now if we choose any $y \in \mathbb{N}$ we can write $f_n(y) = f_n(v) - \sum\limits_{k=v}^{y-1} (f_n(k)-f_n(k+1))$ and obtain the point-wise limit $f(y)$.

Comment: @saz: No problem. Having to write it down made me realize that the point-wise convergence is not that obvious after all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) := 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $v=1$ and define

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases} 0 & x=1 \\ \frac{x-1}{n} & 2 \leq x \leq n+1 \\ 1 & x>n +1\end{cases}.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*} \mathcal{F}(f_n-f) + o_v(f_n-f) &= \mathcal{F}(f_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (f_n(k+1)-f_n(k))^2 = n \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n} \to 0, \end{align*}$$

i.e. $f_n \to f$ in $D$. On the other hand, $$1 = \lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(n) \neq \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0.$$

Comment: @GenericNickname Just out of curiosity: Where did you encounter this? It reminds me a lot of Dirichlet forms....

Comment: It is exactly in the context of Dirichlet forms. I'm currently writing my diploma thesis and I'm using parts of the theory of resistance forms, which are Dirichlet forms if one works on finite sets. I'm currently trying to produce an example showing that a result that I have proven about the Gamma convergence of such forms is not easily generalizable...

Comment: @GenericNickname I see. Good luck :)